# Map an address to a Windows Timezone

Tags: c#, timezone, google-api-timezone

I am looking into mapping a location such as an adress to a Windows TimeZone format. For instance if the address contains the Copenhagen city, then the service should map it to (UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris.

If the address contains a city close to Vienna then it should map it to (UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna.

I have looked into Google's GeoCoding and TimeZone APIs, but it only gives me the name of the timezone like "Central European Time".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a multi-step process:

1. Determine the location's latitude and longitude coordinates.

   - You mentioned Google's geocoding API.  That will do fine, and there are several others to choose from.
2. Determine the time zone identifier from those coordinates using [any of these methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16086964/634824).

   - In most cases, you'll receive an IANA time zone identifier, such as `"Europe/Vienna"`.  You mentioned the Google time zone API - which returns this value in the `timeZoneId` field (*not* `timeZoneName`).
3. Use the IANA time zone identifier to obtain a .NET `TimeZoneInfo` object.

   - If you are running .NET on a non-Windows platform (Linux, OSX, etc.) you can obtain a `TimeZoneInfo` object directly from the IANA time zone identifier:

     ```
     // This will work on platforms that use IANA time zones natively
     TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Europe/Vienna");
     ```
   - If you are running .NET on Windows, or want to write your application to run on *any* platform, then use my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library to retrieve the `TimeZoneInfo` object:

     ```
     // This will work on any platform
     TimeZoneInfo tzi = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("Europe/Vienna");
     ```

If you actually need a Windows time zone identifier, then TimeZoneConverter can do that as well:

```
string tz = TZConvert.IanaToWindows("Europe/Vienna");
//=> "W. Europe Standard Time"
```

Separately, if you want to get the actual string `"(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"`, then:

- If on Windows, and the Windows OS locale is *English*, then you can just get `.DisplayName` from the `TimeZoneInfo` object.
- In all other cases, you can skip step 3 above and just use my [TimeZoneNames](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames) library, which has all display names for all languages:

  ```
  string displayName = TZNames.GetDisplayNameForTimeZone("Europe/Vienna", "en");
  ```

Also, you might consider using [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/) instead of a `TimeZoneInfo` object.

Comment: Thx Matt for the detailed answer. I am fully aware and have done steps 1-2 but description in step 3 is new to me. I will try to implement it as soon as possible and get back to this post.

Comment: HI Matt, I am still researching but so far this method "TimeZoneInfo tzi = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("Europe/Vienna")" is what works for me on my personal laptop, where Regional Settings is set to English. I have to see how it behaves when it runs in an Azure Function for .NET Core runtime. I am trying to get my head around all these terms, IANA, Windows TimeZone identifier, CLDR, POSIX, tz, NodaTime etc.

Comment: What do you *do* with `tzi` after you retrieve it?

Comment: Currently I just store it in a column i database. I have noticed that TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo("Central European Summer Time") cannot be found. I have updated my Win 10 and checked the list of timezone names in Windows Registry with tzutil /l, and this Central European Summer Time actually doesn't exist. But it is valid timezone name.

Comment: If I try to get the timezone name "Central European Summer Time" from NodaTime library it also cannot find this timezone: DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Central European Summer Time"]

Comment: That's because the string `"Central European Summer Time"` is not a valid Windows time zone ID.  `tzutil /l` returns all *Display Names* (localized for the OS's current language) and their corresponding IDs.  The IDs are never localized, and they don't change for daylight/summer time.  In other words, the ID `"Central European Standard Time"` identifies the time zone, regardless of whether standard or summer time is in effect in that time zone.

Comment: Also, the Noda Time TZDB provider is for IANA time zones (like `Europe/Vienna`).  You might want to read through [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) if you haven't yet.  In particular, note the section titled "Time Zone Databases", and pay attention to the details about inconsistencies with naming conventions of Windows time zone identifiers.

Comment: Hi Mat, it works for me when I provide the TimeZone ID from Google TimeZone API result and not the TimeZone Name.

Comment: One more time thanks so much for providing a solution and explaining things in detail. By far the most honest help I have gotten here on SO. I learned a lot about timezones.